# List array output and IBM's Watson Java SDK

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I'm currently working on a translator using IBM's Watson and their [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) imported using Maven, and I'm currently having a hard time trying to figure out how to output the translated text into a text box. The translation results come back to me as:

```
[{
  "translation": "Hello, World !"
}]
```

I think I'm not calling something correctly in my code:

```
LanguageTranslation service = new LanguageTranslation();
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");
TranslationResult translationResult = service.translate(txt_input.getText(), "en", "fr");
txt_translation.setText(translationResult.getTranslations().toString());
```

I think I'm not calling something correctly in my code. According to [the documentation](http://watson-developer-cloud.github.io/java-sdk/docs/java-sdk-2.8.0/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/language_translation/v2/model/TranslationResult.html), the translated text returns as a list of translations, but I'm not sure how to make it output only the translation of what I enter in. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I'm still working out trying to fix the issue. I've tried:

```
java.util.List<Translation> translationText = translationResult.getTranslations();
txt_translation.setText(translationText.toString());
```

With and without the toString() added in. Still comes up as what it did before.

Comment: Isn't that a JSON array value being returned?

Comment: I'm very confident it is, but the one thing that's throwing me for a loop is the fact that it's considered a list. Is there a way in Java to read out of the list?

Comment: oh, I thought that's what you wanted -- since you are calling `toString()`. Sorry, haven't checked the doc thoroughly.

Comment: No problem. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`translationResult.getTranslations()` returns the `List<Translation>`, so it is a list of `Translation` that you should iterate. For instance, in order to get the first translation, you should use:

`translationResult.getTranslations().get(0)`

, which returns `Translation`, and then use `getTranslation()` in order to get translated text.

For instance, translation for the first language should be reachable by:

```
translationResult.getTranslations().get(0).getTranslation()
```

Comment: So, I've got to use getTranslation() twice to make it work?

Comment: It works, just trying to figure out the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for your specific example, just saying that you want from  "en" to "fr" won't work. You have to select an existing translation model first, like this

```
    LanguageTranslation service = new LanguageTranslation();
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("xxx", "xxx");
    //System.out.println(service.getModels()); // <<< get your model from here
    //TranslationResult translationResult = service.translate("Hello World!", "en", "fr"); //<< does not work OOTB
    TranslationResult translationResult = service.translate("Hello World!", "en-fr-conversational");
    System.out.println(translationResult.getTranslations().get(0).getTranslation());
```

so you'll have

```
Bonjour monde !
```

Comment: That was my other problem I was having. I knew I changed something but I couldn't pinpoint what it was. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I uh, tried but couldn't because I don't have enough reputation yet :)